# Why check out master before creating a new branch?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm reading the [Rails Tutorial book](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/updating_and_deleting_users) and, over and over, the author asks the reader to run the following two commands:

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b a
```

I understand what these commands do: they check out the `master` branch, and then create and check out a new branch named `a`.

Why do we need the first line at all? Does it make some difference, or can I just leave it out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you branch, you branch from a specific commit. Checking out master makes sure that your new branch starts from the head (most recent commit) of the master branch.

Answer (score 8):

## TL;DR

> Why do we need the first line at all? [...]

This is a slightly roundabout way of making sure that the new branch, `a`, points at the same commit as `master` does.

## More detailed answer

### What `git checkout -b newbranch` does

To fix ideas, you can think of the `HEAD` pointer as a *You-are-here* mark on the subway map that is your commit graph. Now, the following command,

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

creates and checks out a new branch called `newbranch` that points to *the same commit that `HEAD` (directly or indirectly) points to*. For instance, if your repo looked as follows,

[image]

by running `git checkout -b newbranch`, you would end up with

[image]

### Where Michael Hartl is leading you

However, Michael Hartl (author of the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/)) wants you to create and check out a new branch *that points to a particular commit*: the tip of your `master` branch (i.e. the commit that the `master` branch points to):

[image]

### So, why check out `master` first?

By asking you to run

```
git checkout master
```

Michael Hartl is simply making sure that your `HEAD` points (indirectly) to the right commit, i.e. the tip of `master`:

[image]

Then, running

```
git checkout -b newbranch
```

will definitely create the new branch where desired:

[image]

### A more direct approach: two birds, one stone...

Having to first check out `master` may seem a bit unwieldy, though. You can actually condense those two commands into one:

```
git checkout -b newbranch master
```

No matter where you are in your repo (i.e. where `HEAD` points to), this command will create and checkout a new branch called `newbranch` that points at the tip of `master`.

However, because the Rails tutorial is meant to [cater for people who are new to Git](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/beginning#cha-beginning), and because

```
git checkout -b newbranch master
```

is a bit more advanced and perhaps less intuitive than

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b newbranch
```

you can't really blame Michael Hartl for recommending the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The branch will be created taking as starting commit the one you are when you create the branch. Creating it from Master HEAD is a common pattern, but it depends the branch workflow you want to follow. It's important to have a git workflow and all people in the project follow the same patters in order to maintainability and cowork of all members. Check [this link](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows) to see some of the most commons git workflows.

Comment: The first part of your answer is correct (+1), but Git workflows (understood as collaboration workflows) are a bit off-topic, here. *How* you arrive at a particular situation in your own local repo is your own business, not that of your collaborators, really.